# Archiving and unArchiving custom objects with NSCoder

Tags: swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I am trying to archive an array of photo() objects with some members in it. Given that NsCoding protocol has been implemented correctly, will the following code work to successfully archive (save) the data from the array and anarchive it again?

```
var dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) [0] as String
var dir2 = "/photo.plist"

//This method is suppose to archive objects if the array is not empty.

func archivePhoto ( ) {
    let archiveName =   self.dir + self.dir2
   if ( photos.count > 0 ){
        for photo in photos {
            NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(photo, toFile: archiveName)
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotosCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     archivePhoto()
    let archiveName =   self.dir + self.dir2
    if let myArray =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archiveName) as Array<Photo>? {
         photos = myArray
         self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: "will the following code work to successfully archive (save) the data from the array and anarchive it again? At the moment it's not doing that." If it's not doing that, then obviously no, it won't work. What's the question?

Comment: @matt sorry for the confusion, I will edit my question. But could you help me point out my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Well, just look at your code if you want to know what's wrong with it.

- When you *archive*, you archive *each photo individually*:

  ```
  NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(photo, toFile: archiveName)
  ```

  Moreover, you use the same `archiveName` each time through that loop, so what do you end up with in the archive? *One photo.*
- But when you *unarchive*, you apparently expect to receive an *array* of photos:

  ```
  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archiveName) as Array<Photo>
  ```

  You *don't* receive it, because that is not what you archived in the first place, is it? If you want to archive an array of photos, archive an *array* of photos - not one photo over and over.

I'm not saying that fixing this will solve everything - you do not show any of the other relevant code, such as what `photos` is, what a Photo is, how it encodes / decodes itself, etc., so I have no reason to believe that any of that is working either - but the code that you *do* show will obviously *never* work as it stands, because it makes no sense.

Comment: thanks a lot :-) I still have some issues by my code as my app doesn't load the objects once I quit it and come back on. Thanks I have fixed my archive function